prompt keeps popping up when i close it
 function getHumanChoice() {
      
      let humanChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors:');
      
      if (humanChoice.toLowerCase() !== humanChoice){
        humanChoice = humanChoice.toLowerCase()
      }


      while (humanChoice !== 'rock' && humanChoice !== 'paper' && humanChoice !== 'scissors') {
        alert('Please enter a valid choice');
        humanChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors:');
      }
      
      return humanChoice
    }



I get a typeError in the console whenever I try to close the prompt.
since the error is caused by executing toLowerCase() to null i tried to solve it by an if statement, i got rid of the error but the prompt keeps showing up and console doesnt do anything anymore.
if(humanChoice === null){
        return null
} else {
        if (humanChoice.toLowerCase() !== humanChoice){
          humanChoice = humanChoice.toLowerCase()
        }


        while (humanChoice !== 'rock' && humanChoice !== 'paper' && humanChoice !== 'scissors') {
          alert('Please enter a valid choice');
          humanChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors:');
        }
        
        return humanChoice
}

UPDATE:
I was able to fix it like this
function getHumanChoice() {
      let humanChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors:');

      if (humanChoice === null) {
        return null;
      }

      humanChoice = humanChoice.toLowerCase();

      while (humanChoice !== 'rock' && humanChoice !== 'paper' && humanChoice !== 'scissors') {
        alert('Please enter a valid choice');
        humanChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors:');
      }

      return humanChoice;
}


No need for if (humanChoice.toLowerCase() !== humanChoice). There's no harm in converting the choice to lowercase if it already is.

What does the rest of the script do if getHumanChoice() returns null?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Maybe try to convert it to a string before lowercasing it: humanChoice.toString().toLowerCase(), which in the case of null (cancelling a dialog), will just be the string "null".

Instead of using truthy/falsey directly in the while loop, use this:
// initialize the variable to hold the function.
let getHumanChoice;

getHumanChoice = function (wasEmpty = !1) {
  if (wasEmpty) {alert("Sorry, that was empty or invalid!")}

  // first, initialize the variables in the local space.
  let answer, answered;
  answered = !1; // !1 = false
      
  // loop, only if nothing is in the string
  while (!answered) {
    answer = prompt("Please pick: rock, paper, or scissors!", '');
    if (answer !== '') {answered = !0; /*!0 = true*/}
  }
      
  // use regular expressions to capture the three choices and test is the result ISN'T one of the three.
  if (!(/rock|paper|scissors/i).test(answer)) {return getHumanChoice(!0)}
      
  return answer;
}


This is alot of stuff for just needing a simple loop breack.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
